# The used table type doesn't support FULLTEXT indexes (moodle, mysql, phpmyadmin)

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, centos, moodle

I tried to import my mysql through phpmyadmin and I got this error `The used table type doesn't support FULLTEXT indexes`, I'm using centos server, mysql, import from phpmyadmin and this error I got from moodle database

```
CREATE TABLE `mdliq_search_simpledb_index` (
  `id` bigint(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `docid` varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `itemid` bigint(10) NOT NULL,
  `title` longtext DEFAULT NULL,
  `content` longtext DEFAULT NULL,
  `contextid` bigint(10) NOT NULL,
  `areaid` varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `type` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
  `courseid` bigint(10) NOT NULL,
  `owneruserid` bigint(10) DEFAULT NULL,
  `modified` bigint(10) NOT NULL,
  `userid` bigint(10) DEFAULT NULL,
  `description1` longtext DEFAULT NULL,
  `description2` longtext DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `mdliq_searsimpinde_doc_uix` (`docid`),
  KEY `mdliq_searsimpinde_owncon_ix` (`owneruserid`,`contextid`),
  FULLTEXT KEY `mdliq_search_simpledb_index_index` (`title`,`content`,`description1`,`description2`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COMMENT='search_simpledb table containing the index data.';
```

## 1214 - The used table type doesn't support FULLTEXT indexes

Comment: which version of MySQL you are using? Before 5.6 only MyISAM engine supports `FULLTEXT` search.

Comment: mysql  Ver 15.1 Distrib 5.5.64-MariaDB, for Linux (x86_64) using readline 5.1 @mitkosoft